# Windows 10 - RAM usage constantly increases in Paged Pool, but no process is using the RAM

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

My computer has 32 GB of RAM. The RAM used increases from a minimal amount (<5GB) on startup, to 29 GB before stabilizing. This causes programs (web browser, VM, etc.) to crash for lack of memory.

Using RamMap I can determine the primary issue is that the Paged Pool is using a large amount of the memory, though other types are using a lot of memory as well. Following is a screen shot with only a few programs (browser, VM, RamMap, Process Explorer, etc.) opened: [image: RamMap with Paged Pool]

If I look at Task Manager, the memory usage is also high but no process is claiming the memory(notice the very low compressed memory): [image: Task Manager high memory usage overall] [image: Task Manager low usage by processes]

Using poolmon says that "EtwD" and "Etwr" are causing most of the demand:

[image: poolmon blaming EtwD and Etwr]

I followed along with this example - [Very high ram usage, unusually high non-paged pool use by tag Etwr](https://superuser.com/questions/1155986/very-high-ram-usage-unusually-high-non-paged-pool-use-by-tag-etwr) - and turned off all of the Event Trace Sessions, though I didn't turn off the Startup Trace Event Sessions. I am still getting a very high RAM usage, and it doesn't seem to decline even after a while. When I restarted the computer the Event Trace Sessions were turned back on.

What are the possible reasons left? Could the issue be the Startup Trace Event Sessions? I am going to try that to rule it out, but it seems like I need to Delete them, and I can't just disable them

Comment: If you boot Windows into a minimal configuration does the memory leak still happen?

Comment: I've determined that I can boot up and launch a number of programs before this occurs. It seems like the program Amazon Workspaces, which I use for my Virtual Machine access, is the culprit. I've tried to reinstall it, but that doesn't seem to have fixed it. What are other possible ways around this seeming memory leak?

Comment: "What are other possible ways around this seeming memory leak?" - I assume you have attempted to install the current version, instead of an archive copy, you already downloaded.  I can't seem to find very much information on Amazon Workspaces, except it's required, to access Linux based AWS VMs since they cannot be accessed through a browser.

Comment: Yep, I've redownloaded and reinstalled Amazon Workspaces. In this case I'm using it from a Windows machine to access a Windows VM.