# Very high ram usage, used by tag EtwD and Etwr

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-management, event-viewer, memory-leaks

Ever since I received my laptop I have been running out of RAM randomly (usually while gaming). After extensive monitoring I was able to identify that the Tag `ETwD` and `Etwr` in poolmon are the cause of the high paged and non-paged pool. Running out of ram typically takes a few hours, but can sometimes happen within 1-2hrs while gaming.

As an example after 16.5hrs of uptime the paged pool is `35.3 GB` and the non-paged pool is `5.0 GB`. I am running `Windows 10 Home, 22H2 19045.3448`.

As part of debugging why the event tracer is causing this memory leak I followed guidance in https://superuser.com/a/1156174 and attempted to disable most of the `Startup Event Trace Sessions`. The only ones that remain enabled (see screenshot below) are ones that automatically re-enabled after restart, or could not be disabled due to a permission issue. I also looked in `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs` and noticed that a few were high in side, but not particularly large.

After disabling of the event trace sessions I am no longer able to open `Event Viewer` as the service is unavailable and fails to start due to `Error 4201: The instance name passed was not recognized as valid by a WMI data provider.` Is this error due to the disabling of those events? How can I fix this?

Also, what can I do to further debug the problem and identify what software/driver is causing the memory issue?

[image: Task Manager - Memory]

[image: RAMMap64 - Use Counts]

[image: RAMMap64 - Priority summary]

[image: Poolmon - Bytes sorted]

[image: Startup Event Trace Sessions]

[image: Error 4201]

[image: winevt/Logs]